# Python to remove duplicates using only some, not all, columns

Tags: python, file, duplicates, csv

I have a tab-delimited input.txt file like this

```
A    B    C
A    B    D
E    F    G
E    F    T
E    F    K
```

These are tab-delimited.

I want to remove duplicates only when multiple rows have the same 1st and 2nd columns.

So, even though 1st and 2nd rows are different in 3rd column, they have the same 1st and 2nd columns, so I want to remove "A    B    D" that appears later.

So output.txt will be like this.

```
A    B    C
E    F    G
```

If I was to remove duplicates in usual way, I just make the lists into "set" function, and I am all set.

But now I am trying to remove duplicates using only "some" columns.

Using excel, it's just so easy.

Data -> Remove Duplicates -> Select columns

Using MatLab, it's easy, too.

import input.txt -> Use "unique" function with respect to 1st and 2nd columns -> Remove the rows numbered "1"

But using python, I couldn't find how to do this because all I knew about removing duplicate  was using "set" in python.

===========================

This is what I experimented following undefined_is_not_a_function's answer.

I am not sure how to overwrite the result to output.txt, and how to alter the code to let me specify the columns to use for duplicate-removing (like 3 and 5).

```
import sys
input = sys.argv[1]

seen = set()
data = []
for line in input.splitlines():
    key = tuple(line.split(None, 2)[0])
    if key not in seen:
        data.append(line)
        seen.add(key)
```

Comment: Are you checking only consecutive rows? Lets say you have ABF in your input as 6th row. Should it be removed?

Comment: @Lafexlos  Yes that should be removed. Whether it's consecutive or not, if it's duplicate, it should be regarded as duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

You should use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for this. Here I am grouping the data based on first first two columns and then using [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) to get the first item from each group.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby                                   
>>> s = '''A    B    C                                              
A    B    D
E    F    G
E    F    T
E    F    K'''
>>> for k, g in groupby(s.splitlines(), key=lambda x:x.split()[:2]):
    print next(g)
...     
A    B    C
E    F    G
```

Simply replace `s.splitlines()` with file object if input is coming from a file.

---

Note that the above solution will work only if data is sorted as per first two columns, if that's not the case then you'll have to use a `set` here.

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> ig = itemgetter(0, 1) #Pass any column number you want, note that indexing starts at 0
>>> s = '''A    B    C
A    B    D
E    F    G
E    F    T
E    F    K
A    B    F'''     
>>> seen = set()
>>> data = []
>>> for line in s.splitlines():
...     key = ig(line.split())
...     if key not in seen:
...         data.append(line)
...         seen.add(key)
...         
>>> data
['A    B    C', 'E    F    G']
```

Comment: can you elaborate on this?

Comment: @undefined_is_not_a_function Thank you! I edited my question to ask you a question. The input data is not sorted as per first two columns. And I am not sure how to overwrite the result to output.txt Lastly, how can flexibly change the code so that it removes duplicates as per, say, 3rd and 5th column?

Comment: @user3123767 Read this tutorial for [File I/O](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) in Python. BTW I've updated my second solution to address the 3, 5th column issue.

Comment: @undefinedisnotafunction Thank you. Could you tell me any easier (=as many examples as possible with step-by-step, line-by-line explanations) tutorial than the official tutorial? I always found the official tutorial too general with insufficient examples and step-by-step explanations. This time again I tried several things in the tutorial but I couldn't do it. And many other non-official tutorials were sometimes easier but not comprehensive.

Comment: @undefinedisnotafunction Nothing really helped.. Can't find any tutorial that really helped me save data to output.txt. I really want to learn python, but no tutorial helps. Even worse, your code showed me "list index out of range" error

Comment: @user3123767 Writing to file is a really basic stuff, you can [post a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if you're facing some specific issue with that.

Comment: @undefinedisnotafunction I tried methods that use codec, those that use with, those that use file.write(data) and all didn't help. I could learn MatLab quite easily. The online tutorial was fantastic and a series of Googling always helped a lot. But I can't find a single helpful tutorial of Python yet. Do you know any tutorial that teaches basic stuff comprehensively with lots and lots of examples?

Comment: @undefinedisnotafunction And why is there "list index out of range" error ?

Comment: @user3123767 May be because some of the lines don't have the enough columns. For example if you're passing `ig(3, 4)` and the line contains only four columns then you'll get `IndexError`.(Also don't forget indexing starts at 0 in Python)

Comment: @undefinedisnotafunction I did `ig = itemgetter(0, 1)` , and getting the index error. I checked the file and it's not empty in the 1st and 2nd columns.

Comment: @undefinedisnotafunction I posted a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25079516/python-removing-duplicates-and-saving-the-result

Answer (score 2):

if you have access to a Unix system, sort is a nice utility that is made for your problem.

```
sort -u -t$'\t' --key=1,2 filein.txt
```

I know this is a Python question, but sometimes Python is not the tool for the task. And you can always embed a system call in your python script.

Answer (score 0):

from the below code, you can do it.

```
file_ = open('yourfile.txt')
lst = []
for each_line in file_ .read().split('\n'):
    li = each_line .split()
    lst.append(li)
dic = {}
for l in lst:
    if (l[0], l[1]) not in dic:
        dic[(l[0], l[1])] = l[2]

print dic
```

sorry for variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have already read your object, and that you have an array named rows(tell me if you need help with that), the following code should work:

```
entries = set()
keys = set()
for row in rows:
   key = (row[0], row[1]) # Only the first two columns

   if key not in keys:
      keys.add(key)
      entries.add((row[0], row[1], row[2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

please notice that I am not an expert but I still have ideas that may help you.

There is a csv module useful for csv files, you might go see there if you find something interesting.

First I would ask how are you storing those datas ? In a list ?

something like

```
[[A,B,C],
[A,B,D],
[E,F,G],...]
```

Could be suitable. (maybe not the best choice)

Second, is it possible to go through the whole list ?

You can simply store a line, compare it to all lines.

I would do this : 
suposing list contains the letters.

```
copy = list
index_list = []
for i in range(0, len(list)-1):
    for j in range(0, len(list)-1): #and exclude i of course
     if copy[i][1] == list[j][1] and copy[i][0] == list[j][0] and i!=j:
          index_list.append(j)
for i in index_list: #just loop over the index list and remove
list.pop(index_list[i])
```

this is not working code but it gives you the idea. It is the simplest idea to perform your task, and not likely the most suitable. (and it will take a while, since you need to perform a quadratic number of operations). 
Edit : pop; not remove